# C# - How to write a repository layer for generic wrapper over dynamoDB SDK

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, amazon-dynamodb, .net-6.0

I want to verify if I'm doing the right thing and how to do DI for the parameterized constructor.

**1. Created a interface to get DBContext**

```
     public interface IDBFactory
        {
            DynamoDBContext GetDynamoDBContext();
    
            DynamoDBContext GetDynamoDBContext(DynamoDBContextConfig config);
    
        }
```

**2. Created a class to get AWS profile by implementing IDBFactory**

```
    public class DBFactory : IDBFactory
        {
     public DBFactory(string awsProfile)
            {
                var sharedFile = new SharedCredentialsFile();
                sharedFile.TryGetProfile(awsProfile, out var profile);
                AWSCredentialsFactory.TryGetAWSCredentials(profile, sharedFile, out var credentials);
                amazonDynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, profile.Region);
            }
    
    public DynamoDBContext GetDynamoDBContext()
            {
                DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(amazonDynamoDBClient);
                return context;
            }
        }
```

**3. Created a generic interface**

```
        public interface IGenericDbContext<T> : IDisposable where T : class
            {
                Task<T> GetByIdAsync(string id);
                Task SaveAsync(T item);
                Task DeleteByIdAsync(T item);
            }
```

**4. Created a class extending the interface**

```
     public class GenericDbContext<T> :  IGenericDbContext<T>
             where T : class
        {
               public GenericDbContext(IDBFactory DBFactory, DynamoDBContextConfig config = null)
                {
                    
                }  
         /// Implementation of methods using DynamoDB SDK
        }
```

**So the first question is, Am I correct till now with the architecture?**

Now all this code will go under a nuget package.

So I have to create another repository and install the nuget package so my new repository should be again generic, and I'm not sure how to do this, I tried this one, but it seems incorrect and duplicated.

```
public interface IStore<T> : IGenericDbContext<T> where T : class
```

What is the correct way to have another repository layer which is generic, please note that the nuget package that I created is distributable and I have to consume that in my repository layer.

Apart from that I'm not able to do dependency injection for the parameterized constructor,
I tried below, but it fails.

```
services.AddScoped<IDBFactory>(provider => new DBFactory("default"));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericDbContext<>), typeof(GenericDbContext<>))
```

**Please help me with the architecture and my DI failing logic for the parameterized constructor.**

Comment: No, it's not OK. A DbContext is an EF Core class. Naming your class `DbContext` isn't going to make it one. A DbContext  actually is a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. It's already generic - the specific entities it controls are specified through the `DbSet<>` properties or `Set<T>()` calls. A DbSet<> is a single-entity repository. DbContext is a UoW because it tracks changes to *all* the DbSet<> repos it owns. `SaveChanges` saves *all* pending changes to *all* tracked entities in a single transaction.

Comment: Don't try to name your classes after other libraries, or blindly follow "best practices". You need to really understand what the Repository and Unit-of-Work patterns are about and what problems they solve *before*  you can start implementing them. All the "repository" examples you've seen that build on top of DbContext aren't even repositories and all the useful behavior is *already* implemented by EF Core. In most cases, these examples only add bugs instead of useful features. With DynamoDB though, there's no EF Core provider to offer UoW, tracking and repos. You'll have to write those

Comment: Are you trying to abstract the [Object Persistence Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-intro.html#dynamodb-intro-apis-object-persistence)?  These examples talk about DynamoDB contexts, not Dynamo DbContexts. A DynamoDB context offers none of the UoW functionality of a UoW. A good repository should hide whether you use the Object, document or low-level API.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's a Object Persistence Model, however, the generic classes I have written, it's not wrong, we have crud operations to perform.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos DynamoDB Context does provide different operations to perform, however, it's not straightforward like GET, SAVE, UPDATE and DELETE, I want to simplify that and before using the actual endpoints we have a few configurations that would be required before calling, if you see some flaw in my design please point it out and let me know the alternative solution,  with my design, I'm trying to avoid client/consumer to install the AWS SDK package.